# how to fix the flutter inspector? It just shows activating dart dev tools nothing else. it's just stuck

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have been working with flutter for the last few days in Android studio Everything seems great but just one thing strikes me always the ***flutter inspector just does not work***. this irritates a lot.
i tried a lot of fixes like removing it from the sidebar and replacing it and many more.
pls help me with this issue. i have attached the picture of the issue.